# Invoke postgres commands via Java Runtime.getruntime.exec()

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Initially I ran this code without the leading `"cmd"` and I received an access denied message.  Postgres is being run as a service by an account that cannot be logged into and I am an administrator running this application.  The attempt with `"cmd"` included returns me no input.  My question is how do I go about executing these statements to achieve the resulting files and data changes?

```
 String[] psqlCommands = {"cmd ",postgresLocation, " -dDatabase ", " -UUser ",
                "-c ",  "UPDATE host.user SET service = 1 WHERE service = 1;" +
                        "UPDATE host.permission SET service = 1 WHERE service = 2"};
       Runtime.getRuntime().exec(psqlCommands);

        String[] pgDumpCommands = {"cmd ", postgresLocation, " --data-only ",
                "-t host.user_info -t host.permission -t host.group -t host.account -t host.password " +
                        "-UUser Database> "
                        + DATA + "\\dataExport.sql"};

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pgDumpCommands);
```

The exception that is generated is an `Access Denied` exception that is on the `Postgres_Bin` directory.  I will post a trace once I get the necessary materials.

`Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "d:\program f
iles\postgres\bin": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)

        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)

        at Thing.main(Thing.java:85)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)

        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)

        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)

        ... 4 more`

Comment: cmd is not needed, can you post some exception or error message you got

Comment: It was access denied, I will highlight that in my post

Comment: Access Denied seems very generic error message more details would be useful ,Further I would suggest you to bindup your queries in sql file and dump that

Comment: I will return with the full trace in a moment

Comment: What are you trying to execute? What's `postgresLocation`? Some of the parameters are valid for `psql` and others - for `pg_dump` but I can't see where you mention the appropriate tool. But given the "access denied" message I believe you're trying to dump to a directory you have no rights to.

Comment: Is that an "access denied" from the operating system or from Postgres?

Comment: @Milen on the postgres command line you don't

Comment: @Woot4Moo Indeed that's not mandatory (tho still a good practice).

Comment: @org.life.java Just posted, sorry I had to strip out names of things

Comment: @Milen most likely, I may refactor as such for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program  "d:\program files\postgres\bin"

This error indicates that the spaces in the path confuse the exec() call (and the directory *bin* is indeed nothing that Windows can run)

Make sure you enclose the full path to the .exe with double quotes because of the spaces.

I think using ProcessBuilder is recommended over using exec() as you can specify the arguments and the program to run with different parameters avoiding the escaping of path names with spaces.

Comment: dear sweet jeebus I can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 2):

From the error it looks like you're trying to run the directory, and not appending "psql" or "pg_dump" to get the actual executable name.

I would also believe you wouldn't need to include the "cmd" on the beginning, so try taking that out again.

Answer (score 1):

First if you want to run something in context of windows shell you have to use `cmd /c`. Otherwise you are just running cmd itself. This is the reason that you do not get anything.

When fix your code you are expected to get access denied exactly as you got when you did not use cmd because it seems that you do not have enough permissions. To solve the problem
1. fix your permissions
2. if it is impossible try to run external process as different user using `runas` command.